# seleniumのPhantomJS上でHTML要素のheight,widthを取得する方法

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium

## 目的

http://www.tenki.jp/forecast/3/16/4410/13208.html
このページの「調布市の警報・注意報」部分のheight,widthの取得

## やったこと

```
from selenium import webdriver
URL = "http://www.tenki.jp/forecast/3/16/4410/13105-daily.html"
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get(URL)
print(driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByClassName('class')[1].offsetWidth;"))
```

[参考]
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42610379/how-to-get-a-websites-body-width-with-selenium-and-python
しかし、最終行で
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
(省略)
Screenshot: available via screen
とでてきます。
しかし、最終行を

```
print(driver.execute_script("return document.body.offsetWidth;")
```

としたところ400という数字が返ってきたので、仮想ブラウザ上でも要素のheightは取得できると考えました。

driver.execute_script()は元のhtmlにjsを挿入してその結果を受け取るものだと解釈したので、DOMの書式に従って

```
document.getElementsByClassName('class')[1].offsetWidth
```

としたのですが、何がいけないのでしょうか？
https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

また、
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664000/how-to-programmatically-measure-the-elements-sizes-in-html-source-code-using-py
によればGhostというライブラリを用いれば可能なようなのですが、PysideやPyQtを入れたくないので、seleniumでの解決法を知りたいです。

Answer (score 2):

`"Screenshot: available via screen"` というのは、例外メッセージの末尾でおまけとして「例外オブジェクトの中に、エラーが発生したときのスクリーンショットデータも入ってるから参考にしてね！」と言われているだけで、問題の原因とは関係が無いと思います。
実際の原因に直結するメッセージはその直前、 **(省略)** とされてしまっている部分に　JSON 形式等で出力されていると思いますので、そこを改めて確認してみては如何でしょうか。

因みに、同じコードを私の手元で実行した場合、次のような JSON が返されていました。

```
{'errorMessage': "'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementsByClassName('class')[1].offsetWidth')",
 'request': {'headers': {'Accept': 'application/json',
   'Accept-Encoding': 'identity',
   ...
}
```

つまり、単に `document.getElementsByClassName('class')[1]` が `undefined` だと言われているだけのようです。

#### 参考

尚、上述の「例外発生時のスクリーンショットデータ」は次のような感じで取得できますので、もしかしたら問題解決の参考になるかもしれません。

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
import base64

try:
    result = driver.execute_script(...)
except WebDriverException as e:
    if e.screen:
        with open('exception.png', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(base64.b64decode(e.screen))
```